# issue with hierarchical custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I use WordPress 4.7 hosted on a W2012 server with MySQL 5.7.9 and PHP 7.
I have a child theme, and in my child theme, I have created a custom post type with the code below.
In WP settings, permalinks structure are set to "post name".
Permalinks work fine for pages and posts, but I have strange behaviors with my custom post type.

I have created a custom post type with slug 'accueil-parcours-107' under parent custom post type with slug 'place-01'.

When I enter https://responsive.knowledgeplaces.com/accueil-parcours-107/
I am redirected to https://responsive.knowledgeplaces.com/places/place-01/accueil-parcours-107/

I would like to get a 404 error, how can I do this?

Here is the code for custom post type:

```
register_post_type( 'kpcms_place',
array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Knowledge Places Pages', 'KPCMS' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Knowledge Place Page', 'KPCMS' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add a Knowledge Place Page', 'KPCMS' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Knowledge Place Page', 'KPCMS' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Knowledge Place Page', 'KPCMS' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Knowledge Place Page', 'KPCMS' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Knowledge Places Pages', 'KPCMS' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No Knowledge Places Pages found', 'KPCMS' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Knowledge Places Pages found in Trash', 'KPCMS' ),
        'parent_item_column' => __( 'Parent Knowledge Place Page:', 'KPCMS' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Knowledge Places Pages', 'KPCMS' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into Knowledge Place Page', 'KPCMS' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Knowledge Place Page', 'KPCMS' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Knowledge Places' )
    ),
    'query_var' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-location',
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'places'
    ),
    'taxonomies' => array(
        'category',
        'post_tag'
        ),
    'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post'          => 'edit_kpcms_place',
        'read_post'          => 'read_kpcms_place',
        'delete_post'        => 'delete_kpcms_place',
        'edit_posts'         => 'edit_kpcms_places',
        'edit_others_posts'  => 'edit_others_kpcms_places',
        'publish_posts'      => 'publish_kpcms_places',
        'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_kpcms_places',
        'create_posts'       => 'edit_kpcms_places'
    ),
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'author',
        'comments',
        'revisions',
        'page-attributes'
    ),
)
```

);

Comment: I dont have option to add a page from above the code.

Comment: Its displaying only category and tags. Have you updated  the permalinks settings?